# java: how to write a server with apache or lighttpd?

Tags: java, apache, lighttpd

I want to write a server side code in Java to access DB. A request like `http://localhost/name=jack`, will access database and return information of jack.

I want to use Apache or lighttpd webserver. However, most pages about these servers' configuration are about JavaEE, I just want to use javaSE to implement this program, how can I do this?

Comment: Read Servlets, JDBC from Java Trail. Or one of many tutorials on web.

Comment: If you are using Java then you should consider Jetty, the native java HTTP server: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please you java web start, which uses java SE with a plain HTTP server, you will not need a web container/Java EE here.

Comment: you mean if I want to use apache or lighttpd, I must use JavaEE? because I can use php with apache, so I want to know whether there's a way to use apache with javase?

Comment: I mean you can use java SE and use apache or lighttpd. You will need to know what is java web start for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with GlassFish 3. It's free. It has build in JavaDB server.